# Деплои Spring Boot+Angular2 приложения на Heroku

Tags: angular2, spring-boot, heroku

Сделал веб-приложение, бек-енд - Spring, фронт - Angular2. Деплоить решил на Heroku. Деплоится отлично, бек-енд работает превосходно, а вот сам фронт не грузит.
Проект - https://github.com/BarexaS/Constructed.git

```
2016-11-08T15:41:04.303311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=d3c3c81e-e02f-4380-8069-1b7224502e82 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=155ms status=404 bytes=542
2016-11-08T15:41:04.356715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=7c31ae80-f595-4adf-93b6-a9c093d1d8e7 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=193ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T15:41:04.519669+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=7c06414e-4cfb-489f-8d8a-eeab8a14d2c0 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=123ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T15:41:04.680541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=b9e31d43-0ba8-4a84-b21a-50f981bdb7c9 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=38ms status=404 bytes=549
2016-11-08T15:41:04.829222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/systemjs.config.js" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=9a1fb274-6355-  4ff2-a7f1-d7624700ff53 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=18ms status=200 bytes=2077
2016-11-08T15:41:04.992681+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login/blue-sky-hd-wallpaper-2.jpg" host=organazi.herokuapp.com request_id=1c74584b-f2ff-4c3a-9a26-46efb41803f8 fwd="91.196.192.37" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=25ms status=200 bytes=52476
```

Вот в это и проблема, файл "systemjs.config.js" как и картинку "/login/blue-sky-hd-wallpaper-2.jpg" грузит отлично, а вот сами "node_modules" ангуляра не хочет, уже 2 недели пытаюсь решить проблему, может есть идеи как ее решить?

Comment: Не знаю что такое Heroku, но судя по логам данные файлы просто отсутствуют по запрашиваемым uri, может поглядеть если они собственно там куда деплоятся? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пара комментариев о коде из того, что я вижу в репе:

1. Держать `.idea`, `target` и `node_modules` папки в репозитории - плохое решение, так как размер репозитория очень быстро может превысить доступные пределы. Небольшое обоснование можно найти [здесь](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/03/git-tip-of-week-ignoring-build-output.html).
2. Использование необработанных исходников для любого языка в принципе считается плохим тоном, так как может сильно повлиять на производительность приложения. Обоснование и обзор решений можно найти в [статье о минификации, обфускации и сжатию js/css кода](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) в целях оптимизации производительности. В своей разработке опирайтесь на возможности того же Heroku выполнить pre-deploy шаги, например, сборку maven/gulp проекта.

Как раз в результате того, что вы опирались в деплое на необработанный исходный код библиотек, сыграло злую шутку. Если вы проверите содержимое `node_modules` в ветке `master`, то не найдете там как раз тех файлов, которые не может найти ваше приложение.